# Numerical evaluation of the first and second complete elliptic integrals

Tags: numerical-analysis

To get a numerical evaluation of the first (K) and second (E) complete elliptic integrals:

$$K(k)=\int_0^1\frac{dt}{(1-t^2)^{1/2}(1-k^2t^2)^{1/2}}, \ \ \ \ \ E(k)=\int_0^1\frac{(1-k^2t^2)^{1/2}}{(1-t^2)^{1/2}}dt$$

in a left neighbourhood of the point $k=1$. What numerical methods do you recommend to get a "good" approximation of K and E in a left neighbourhood of the point $k=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A truncated power series about $k=1$ is one way. You can find several forms at [functions.wolfram.com](http://functions.wolfram.com) for [$K(k)$](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticK/06/01/04/01/) and [$E(k)$](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticE/06/01/04/01/). The number of terms used should allow you to estimate your error for a given neighborhood size.

Matlab's [`ellipke`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ellipke.html) uses a simple arithmetic–geometric mean method (see [Abramowitz & Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/)) to find values for any $k$.

Answer (score 0):

The scipy package for Python has [ellipkm1](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.ellipkm1.html#scipy.special.ellipkm1) "The complete elliptic integral of the first kind around m=1."

Comment: Sadly this function is a very limited implementation, it works only for real arguments 0 <= m <= 1. So it is not really practical.